# &-sign is ruining my link-rewriter

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I'm currently writing a userscript that runs on another site. One function is to rewrite the links so you skip one landing page. However, if the &-sign exists in the link, my function will output it as `&amp;` instead of `&`.

```
        $('a').each(function(index) {
        var aLink = $(this).attr('href');
        if(aLink) {
            if(aLink.indexOf("leave.php?u=") > 0) {
                aLink = aLink.substring(38);
                $(this).attr('href', decodeURIComponent(aLink));
            }

        }
    });
```

This is one example of a link that gets ruined:

```
 https://www.site.com/exit.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsverigesradio.se%2Fsida%2Fartikel.aspx%3Fprogramid%3D104%26amp%3Bartikel%3D3406950
```

Is a link to:

```
 http://sverigesradio.se/sida/artikel.aspx?programid=104&artikel=3406950
```

But becomes this instead:

```
 http://sverigesradio.se/sida/artikel.aspx?programid=104&amp;artikel=3406950
```

Comment: It is double encoded, so you should also double decode it.

Comment: @Topener, you mean like just apply decodeURIComponent twice?

Comment: @mgraph, tried that and got a relative link, not absolute.

Comment: @Topener, it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`&amp;` entity](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) is built right into that URL, so there's nothing for it except to just replace it.

Use:

```
aLink = aLink.substring (38);
aLink = decodeURIComponent (aLink);
aLink = aLink.replace (/&amp;/gi, "&");
$(this).attr ('href', aLink);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a adaptable solution if the same occurs with any other sign...

Comment: It doesn't occur with any other character, and `&amp;` is not a "sign" it is an **entity** -- which is a very specific thing in HTML.  You only need be concerned where entities (that are actually used) overlap deliminator characters for URL's.  That's just `&amp;` and no others.